# Mvvm-Light User Control RelayCommand TemplateBinding

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, uwp, mvvm-light

> [UWP - Windows 10]

I'm new to MVVM-Light and so I got some starter issues. I created a custom Usercontrol which is called `TileToolbar` and is containing this xaml:

```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource NavRadioButtonStyle}" Tag="&#xE141;" Foreground="Green"></RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource NavRadioButtonStyle}" Tag="&#xE7E6;" Foreground="Green"></RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource NavRadioButtonStyle}" Tag="&#xEB52;" Foreground="Green"></RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

Now I want to add a `RelayCommand` for each RadioButton and I want each Page which is containing the custom usercontrol to be able to bind a custom `RelayCommand`.

- My first Approach was to set the `Command` Property in xaml and to implement the method in the viewmodel (e.g. `MainViewModel`) which actually worked  - shorten xaml:`<RadioButton Command="{Binding Command}"></RadioButton>`
- Because I wanted to **set the Propery in the Page using the customcontrol** like this `<TileToolbar PinCommand={Binding Command}></TileToolbar>` I created a dependency property of type RelayCommand but the TemplateBinding didn't work.

So my question:
How would I create a property like `PinCommand` of type `RelayCommand` in the UserControl so I can later bind to it in xaml for example on the `Mainpage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question: How would I create a property like PinCommand of type RelayCommand in the UserControl so I can later bind to it in xaml for example on the Mainpage?

You can register a `PinCommand` in the type of `RelayCommand` in your `UserControl`'s code behind for example like this:

```
public static DependencyProperty PinCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PinCommand", typeof(RelayCommand), typeof(TileToolbar), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public RelayCommand PinCommand
{
    get
    {
        return (RelayCommand)GetValue(PinCommandProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(PinCommandProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Now you can use this `TileToolbar` in your `MainPage` for example like this:

```
<Controls:TileToolbar Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" PinCommand="{Binding pinCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Code in view model is like this:

```
private RelayCommand _pinCommand;

public RelayCommand pinCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_pinCommand == null)
        {
            _pinCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                //TODO:
            },
            () => true);
        }
        return _pinCommand;
    }
}
```

And for the work of connecting the `Command` of `RadioButton` to the `PinCommand` of `TileToolBar`, you can in your user control for example code like this:

```
<RadioButton Tag="&#xEB52;" Foreground="Green" Command="{x:Bind PinCommand, Mode=OneWay}"></RadioButton>
```